# Magento 2 : Disable Sending email when order status change

Tags: magento2, sales-order

Is their any way we can stop sending email when order status change from backend magento 2  ?

any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
STORES > SETTINGS > CONFIGURATION > SALES > Sales Emails > Order > Set Enabled field as No
```

Check Once

Comment: It will disable only email for order status change ? Or all order email ?

Comment: For Order Operations only.

Comment: Thanks but what if customer places order ? does customer get email ?

Comment: Probably no, check that once. Please accept this as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can disable from your Magento configurations:
Go to:

> STORES > Under SETTINGS > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > Order
>
> > And then SET the Enabled field to NO.

You can disable this for various order status changes.
You can also Disable Email Communications Go to:
`STORES > Under SETTINGS > Configuration > Advanced > System > Open Mail Sending Settings > Disable Email Communications` and set that to yes.
[image]

Comment: It will disable only email for order status change ? Or all order email ?

Comment: You have to disable each for various status changes.

Comment: How that can be done ?

Comment: Check more options below like I have told you for order, check below for invoice, shipment. Disable which you want to disable

Answer (score 0):

I need Magento ver. 2.3.0 to stop sending order confirmation email, if the order payment is not processed and only allow order confirmation email to be sent when the order is complete and client hits success page

Comment: check this one : https://magecomp.com/magento-2-order-confirmation-email.html